# Which is the best c++ library for creating an ip scanner for LAN

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries

I wish to create an ip scanner in C++/Qt, which library would be best, and of course thread safe.

Comment: I'm developing libtins right now, it's still under development, but it fits your needs :P http://libtins.sourceforge.net/

Comment: What limitations are forbidding you to do it in Qt?

Comment: @adnankamili What do you need exactly? Qt has normal socket support.

Comment: @adnankamili Your question shows, that you totaly don't know what you're trying to do. You don't need full protocol support to check if that protocol is available on certain port. To write ip scanner you need only QTcpSocket and you need to know how some protocols work. i.e. to check if there is HTTP server on port XXXX you need to send http GET request, to check if there is an smpt server you need to send smpt "helo" command, for esmpt you send "ehlo" etc. There is no need to use "full support" classes

Comment: suppose the computer on lan has no servers installed, as is the case, most often in college hostels, so how would you detect a system, you need to ping atleast, and how would you ping using QTcpSocket, if it is possible to ping using QTcpSockets, i wud use Qt only. My aim is to check for online hosts, and display their hostnames, response time, shares (if have any using libsmbclient). libsmbclient library only checks on port 139 & 445. So, i need a library which can detect all the live hosts,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best known networks scanners [nmap](http://nmap.org/) uses [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Qt supports many different protocols and I'm sure that you will be able to build an IP-Scanner using the

> QNetwork Module

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/network-programming.html